# WebSphere 6.1 CE Recovery error: SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_recover'

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, websphere

Hi I have inherited a a Websphere 6.1 Community Edition that hosts several applications. They all use the same pooled DB connections to MySql. Yesterday the connection pool would run out after about 2 hours requiring a server restart... ever 2 hours.... not great. So tonight I have all the modules stopped and am going to add them one by one to see which one is the culprit. However, this leads me to the problem in the subject, when the websphere server boots it give me this every 15 minutes:

ERROR [RecoveryController] Recovery error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_recover'.

As far as I know there is no SQL server used in any of the clients apps. Is this something that comes with WS?

How can I get rid of the error?

Extra points, the server.log file is also writing [INFO] entries, where can I turn them off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some old transaction to MSSQL database is still in transaction logs and could not be recovered. It looks like XA is not configured on your database server.

If you are still using that MSSQL server, try to configure XA support, if you don't use it any more you can try to stop WAS CE server and remove old transaction logs, which should be in /var/txlog.

For logging configuration check these two links: [Logging in WAS CE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.1/en/faq.html#FAQ-G3) and [Application logging in WebSphere Application Server Community Edition](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/tutorials/0903_madgula/index.html#5.Community%20Edition%20nuances%20and%20getting%20the%20most%20from%20Log4j%7Coutline)

Comment: The Logging info is spot on! have set everything to WARN. Thankyou. I looked in the /var/txlog there are too files filled with junk but a reference to : c/ActiveDSEOB
or-derby-embed-local-1.7,ResourceAdapterModule=org.apache.geronimo.plugins.monitoring/agent-ds/3.0-w20110721/car,j2eeType=JCAConnectionManager,name=jdbc/ActiveDSEOB Looks like some sort of application that uses derby, that maybe comes with WS CE? Can I delete them?

Comment: This looks like monitoring database - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V3.0.0/en/monitoring-server-components.html - you have to check, if you are using it. But your problem was related to Microsoft SQL server, not Derby database.

Comment: That's right it is related to SQLServer but the reference to derby was in the var/txtlog. As it turns out there is a SQLServer instance that is used by a single process. I will add the XA transaction set up I found here :
    http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21315998 

to see if I can remove the error message. If there are any held transactions in the var/txtlog log files, will they be executed once XA is enabled?

Comment: Yes, they should be. However they are probably already removed on the database side, so you might get errors anyway.